# After you've clipped the lockout chip's 4th pin on a toaster-style NES, do you still get the flashing red light and screen with no cartridge?

Tags: mods, nes

Just curious as I have not yet performed the fix, and it seems like logically, if this 1-second cyclic reset is chip-associated behavior, you'd just see a solid lavender or black/grey screen with no cartridge after the lockout fix. Can anyone confirm?  I'll update this if and when I go ahead with that and test.

Comment: It would be useful if you could describe this procedure to us. I realize this question might only be answerable by people knowing what you're talking about in the first place, but it's a lot more useful if the uninitiated could follow along.